# facebook login to my site

Tags: facebook

I created a website and now want to allow users to login using facebook, as well as my login system.
I have added the code below which gives me a login using facebook button, this then prompts me for username and password which i enter then when i click login, it disappears and my browser does not redirect anywhere. Where am i going wrong?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });
</script>
<fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

Comment: Either I do not fully understand your intent, or this sounds *malicious*.

Comment: Sorry i think i have not explained myself properly. I simply am trying to allow users to sign up to my site using their facebook their facebook credentials. Oviously i will not be getting their credentials but will be getting their email address etc.

Comment: It may be a good idea to edit your question to reflect as much.

Answer (score 1):

the fb:login-button tag may not be what you want.  I would create your own button and then use the facebook javascript Login method to login your user.

```
<button type="button" onclick="doLogin()">Log in Here PPL!</button>
```

then in a script tag

```
var doLogin = function() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
         //they're logged in!  we've got them!
         location='/product/sell_it_now';
       } else {
         console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
       }
     }, {scope: 'email'});
}
```

from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Answer (score 0):

May be you trying this on localhost machine.

For more info follow up wit instruction on Facebook documents which clear login process:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web